# open file c++ error

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to open a file in c++.

My file is located in /home/me/myproject/mydir/myfile.txt

I checked in my file system that the file exists and is not empty.

I checked with getcwd() that I'm in /home/me/myproject/

Hence I tried to open it with :

```
string myfilename;
ifstream myfile;
myfilename = "./mydir∕myfile.txt"; 
myfile.open(myfilename.c_str(), ios::in);
if (myfile.fail()) {
    // I always end up here.
}
```

I really fail to understand why myfile.fail() always returns true. Any idea why it is, or what debug tests I could perform to understand why it's behaving that way ?

---

I found what's wrong, thanks to all. I am using a remote control software, which apparently considers that "/" (forward slash) is different from "/" (division character). I still have one question troubling me though, but I'll ask it in another post. The errno and strerror() helped me to understand what's wrong. These errors are hard to find, and sorry it wasn't strictly related to the c++ code.

(note: I answered here because apparently I can't answer my own question).

Comment: Try using the absolute path `/home/me/myproject/mydir/myfile.txt` to open the file.

Comment: I'd think that would work, but be sure to check the filesystem permissions that the process you're running has read access to that file.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions

Comment: When the opeing fail, print out the value of `errno`, or maybe [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) to get a readable string.

Comment: The permissions are -rw-r--r--, so I suppose it would work. Is there no way to distinguish the type of error, whether it's returning false because it doesn't find it, or because of a permission error ?

Comment: either give the absolute path or related to my Computer....like C://web.txt or D://txtx.txt

Comment: I tried to give the absolute path, but myfile.fail() still returns true. I used strerror(errno), and it answers "Numerical result out of range". I saved errno into a variable right after the call to myfile.fail(), so that nothing would interfere with it.

Comment: @bob what was the numerical value of errno?

Comment: check `myfile.is_open()` before

Comment: also, try with ifstream::in, instead of ios::in.

Comment: @DmitryEskin `ifstream::in` is `ios::in`.  The only definition of `in` in the hierarchy is in `ios_base`; all derived classes inherit it.

Comment: @Ben You're on the right track.  After detecting failure, I'd use `strerror` (with `errno`) to display the error in a human understandable form.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I agree - he should use both. He has already given use `strerror` = "Numerical result out of range", I was just asking for `errno` in addition.

Comment: @bob also please set `errno` to zero before calling `open`, then tell us the value of both `strerror` and `errno` after the call to `open`.

Comment: @bob Did you set `errno` to `0` before opening the file?  Otherwise, it may be an old value.

Comment: I expect you have just made some straightforward mistake, like not being in the correct directory or not having put the file where you thought you did. We've all done it...

Comment: No I hadn't set errno to 0 before opening the file, but I did now and it produced the same result, which is 34.

Comment: Problem solved, see the edit made to the question above for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file using a relative path, it's computed from the execution directory, which depends on how you launch your program.

Suppose your program is located in `~/path/to/my/program`, if your current directory is ~ when you launch it (so your command is `./path/to/my/program/my_program`), the execution directory is ~. If your current directory is ~/path/to/my (and you launch with the `./program/my_program` command), the execution directory is ~/path/to/my. You can determine your current working directory with the `getcwd()` function.

To avoid such problems, a good rule of thumb is to always use absolute paths in your application.

Also, you should use either `errno` or `strerror` in your `if (myfile.fail()) {...}` block to have more information about the error.

Comment: -1, while technically correct: he explicitly stated he used `getcwd()` to check the path.

Comment: I agree and go further - the first action of most executables and scripts (other than command-line tools specifically intended to act on the user's current directory) should be to change the working directory to the location of the executable, and never ever use a relative path.

Comment: I have one question regarding this, but I'll ask it in another post.